# Default entity ID for _entity_view in routing.yml

Tags: 8, routes

I've a custom content entity (created using [Config pages module](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_pages)) which is used as a welcome screen / dashboard. Privileged super editors can edit those content entities, normal editors can only view it.

The config pages module itself does not provide routes to view modes (only to edit forms), so I used the core's generic `_entity_view` to create routes for the normal editors myself:

This is `my_module.routing.yml`

```
my_module.view_config_pages:
  path: '/admin/config_pages/{i_dont_want_no_parameter}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'config_pages.full'
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated'
  options:
    _admin_route: true
    parameters:
        i_dont_want_no_parameter:
          type: 'entity:config_pages'
```

This works with URLs like `/admin/config_pages/1`, `/admin/config_pages/2` etc... But I want to create nice, parameter-less, named routes to specific entity IDs. Something similar to my dummy-code below

```
my_module.view_welcome:
  path: '/admin/welcome'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'config_pages.full'
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated'
  options:
    _admin_route: true
    parameters:
        yeah_no_parameter:
          type: 'entity:config_pages'
          id: 1
my_module.view_stats:
  path: '/admin/stats'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'config_pages.full'
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated'
  options:
    _admin_route: true
    parameters:
        yeah_no_parameter:
          type: 'entity:config_pages'
          id: 2
```

Can this be done with `_entity_view` in YAML files without coding a custom controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ID can be set in the defaults section, here is an example:

```
my_module.view_dashboard:
  path: '/admin/dashboard/{my_entity_id}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'my_custom_entity.full'
    my_entity_id: 123
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated'
    my_entity_id: ^[0-9]+
  options:
    _admin_route: true
    parameters:
      my_entity_id:
        type: 'entity:my_custom_entity'

my_module.view_stats:
  path: '/admin/stats/{my_entity_id}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'my_custom_entity.full'
    my_entity_id: 456
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated'
    my_entity_id: ^[0-9]+
  options:
    _admin_route: true
    parameters:
      my_entity_id:
        type: 'entity:my_custom_entity'
```

This solution creates nice URLs without any controller.